# How can I deploy Aurelia bundles to another directory during build?

Tags: aurelia

I am working on the [Aurelia Sample app](https://github.com/aurelia/app-contacts) and would like to deploy the build output(*vendor-bundle.js* and *app-bundle.js*) to `www-root\scripts` instead of the default `scripts` directory. So I tried modifying the *aurelia.json* to look like:

```json
...
"testFramework": {
    "id": "jasmine",
    "displayName": "Jasmine"
  },
  "build": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "id": "web",
        "displayName": "Web",
        "output": "www-root\\scripts"
      }
    ],
    "loader": {
...
```

Which indeed results in the bundle files to be output to `www-root\scripts` however since I have defined an *HTTP.SYS* alias for my apllication e.g. the landing URL is: [http://localhost/*MyAlias*/](http://localhost/MyAlias/) when I try to browse the app it tries to load the *app-bundle.js* from: `http://localhost/MyAlias/www-root/scripts/app-bundle.js` instead of `http://localhost/MyAlias/scripts/app-bundle.js`.

The *vendor-bundle.js* however is correctly downloaded from: `http://localhost/MyAlias/scripts/vendor-bundle.js`

I cannot figure out what to modify to make this get the *app-bundle.js* from the correct path.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom gulp task to copy the bundled app into `www-root` folder at the end of the building process.
By choosing this approach, there is no need to change `build.targets` in `aurelia.json`.

**1.** Generate a new task using aurelia-cli generators [[documentation]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/4).

Something like this below:

`aurelia_project/tasks/dist.js|ts`

```js
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as project from '../aurelia.json';

export default function dist() {
    return gulp.src(project.dist.sources, { "base" : "." })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(project.dist.output));
}
```

**2.** I think it's better to have a separate config section for publishing, so you'll be able to add other files and folders as well.

`aurelia_project/aurelia.json`

```js
...

"dist": {
    "output": "www-root",
    "sources": [
        "./scripts/**/*",
        "./index.html",
        "<other_resource_to_copy>",
        ...
    ]
},

....
```

**3.** Insert this new task at the end of the building process.

`aurelia_project/tasks/build.js|ts`

```js
export default gulp.series(
    readProjectConfiguration,
    ...
    writeBundles,   
    dist // here goes our custom task
);
```

**4.** Oh, and it works with `au run --watch` as well! :)

If you'd like to try it out, I have a working example [here](https://github.com/martonsagi/aurelia-custom-skeleton).

Comment: This is great! works like a charm. Just a quick question, any way to exclude `require.js` and `text.js` or anything else that I may want from being copied? Sorry a complete *gulp* virgin here!

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I believe you can. Check out "gulp glob options": https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options. e.g. ["./scripts/**/*", "!./scripts/require.js"]

Comment: It says `invalid glob argument` but I will have a go at it later. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone comes here looking for a way to clean up the root directory of an aurelia-cli project, here's a method that builds directly to the location of your choice using the RequireJS or SystemJS loaders:

1. Make a directory for output, let's call it OUTPUT
2. Move `index.html` and `favicon.ico` to OUTPUT
3. Open `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` and edit the following:

   ```
   "build": {
       "targets": [
           {
               "index": "OUTPUT/index.html",
               "baseDir": "OUTPUT",
               "baseUrl": "scripts",
               "output": "OUTPUT/scripts"
           }
       ],
       ...
   }
   ...
   "platform": {
       "index": "OUTPUT/index.html",
       "baseDir": "OUTPUT",
       "baseUrl": "scripts",
       "output": "OUTPUT/scripts"
   },
   ```
4. Test with `au run` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for this answer was going around in a circle for a bit. Works great!